# what is the first thing to teach total beginners

Tags: torah-study, kiruv-outreach

Looking to teach a total beginner (i.e. someone not yet interested in following any halachas) college student for kiruv purposes. What is the best part of torah to teach first?

Is it better (for kiruv purposes) to teach inspirational agadah or grind away some Gemorah, or perhaps tanach with Malbim?

i.e. what is the ideal subject to teach for kiruv purposes, assuming the person is ready to learn anything.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29670, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12749

Comment: Probably depends on the individual.

Comment: In addition to what @DoubleAA said, probably it's best not to go into kiruv unless you have some training and/or experience. I think it's a lot easier to mess it up than to do it right.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with sanders that day-to-day practical halacha should be the "default" starting point.  But I would expand that thought: each person is different, each kiruv situation is different, and the best starting point is the one that will engage *that particular person* at *that particular time*.  As it says in [Mishlei 22:6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16393#v=6), "Train a child according to his way ..." (h/t @IsaacMoses).

For some that way will be the basic b'rachot of daily living.  For some it will be saying and starting to understand the sh'ma daily.  For some it will be torah study with a good chumash.  For some it will be communal ritual like the Pesach seder.  For some it will center on their children.

You need to evaluate each situation -- ask probing questions, pay attention to how the person responds as you proceed, and adjust course as necessary.  I've found the questions that people ask can be illuminating, revealing either an area of interest to explore or a misconception to address.

Per [Avodah Zara 19a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=19&format=text), a person can only learn Torah properly when he is learning a topic that interests him at the time (h/t @Fred).  Find that topic and proceed.

Comment: [*Avoda Zara* 19a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=19&format=text): "א"ר אין אדם לומד תורה אלא ממקום שלבו חפץ שנאמר (תהלים א, ב) כי אם בתורת ה' חפצו". Paraphrased: Rabbi said that a person can only learn Torah properly when he is learning a topic that interests him at the time.

Comment: @Fred thanks!  I've incorporated that into the answer.

Comment: I noticed that Ohr Somayach, which is one of the most successful kiruv organizations teaches gemora b'iyun right off the bat to total beginners. do you think it would be good to model them?

Comment: @ray, I think you're missing the point of this answer. What's successful for some may not be successful for others. This answer is written for an individual would-be mekarev, who has the advantage of being able to (and therefore, says this answer, best-advised to) tailor the program of study to the individual student - an option not available in the same way to an institution.

Comment: @IsaacMoses i happen to agree with that point. but I also think some subjects are much more effective than others for kiruv. This is why ohr somayach FOCUSES on gm b'iyun. I think the impact on the soul is far greater than say kitzur halacha. if a person cant handle it, than maybe better for plan B. but still plan A would be better.

Comment: @ray, If you have sources and/or arguments to back up an answer to this question, why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @ray, the question described what sounded like a one-on-one relationship, which is why I ansered this way.  It also sounds like your college student might not be ready to go off and enroll in a yeshiva like Ohr Somayach.  Have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @MonicaCellio yes, I think so. my question is what is the ideal subject to learn for kiruv purposes, assuming the person is ready to learn anything. thanks alot.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I'm not a kiruv professional so dont have experience, just general knowledge and therefore not qualified to answer.. was hoping someone with experience could clarify.

Comment: @ray, you have an answer here that has experience along with a pasuk and Chazal backing it up. Ashrecha.

Comment: @Ray, "I think so" = yes I have misunderstood your question?  One-on-one kiruv is different from institutional kiruv; which are you asking about?  (Actually, since all the answers here assumed the former, if you meant the latter I'd encourage you to make a new question that's explicit about that.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio one-on-one as in the question. my question was simply what is the ideal subject to learn all else being equal - i.e. if the person is equally interested/motivated,etc. in every subject. which subject is most effective for kiruv purposes.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is critical not just to pick something the student would like, but to pick something which you truly are excited about - this way, when you teach, you can give over the that extra joy of learning your favorite subject, which is a very important motivational device as well...

In terms of fitting the student, for the thinking type, I generally prefer the *chumash*. It is a good area where you can bring in philosophy and *drush* to show many layers of meaning in the text. The idea of a multi-layered text is critical to learning any area of Jewish life, be it *gemara* or *halacha* with arguing opinions, or *mussar* with interpretation of life on multiple layers, or even the art of living a life balancing all different kinds of responsibilities, each of which can be loosely interpreted as a layer of meaning in the life of a person. For me this is the most effective way of showing depth, which the thinking type usually reacts very well to.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing is to start with day to day practical things. For example הלכה. These are things which are important every day.

Along the line you could start with other things like פרשת השבוע or משנה